# Sending emails from form POST data using Django

Tags: django, forms, email

So I've written HTML code for a form that I want to send emails with using Django. From everything I have seen, the Django email is being used with Django's own form module in order to send emails with the data. I am wondering if it is possible at all to keep my current HTML form and access its POST data to use with Django's email functions?

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here. You can use any form in a view and then send the data from it. What is your exact problem?

Comment: I'm trying to use Django's send_mail function, but I don't know how to access the data from my HTML form to use in the message parameter of that function. Everything else I have looked up uses Django's own form class to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a django Form object (like a ContactForm) : your form's POST data can be accessed through the `request` argument of your view.

This example was taken from the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#preventing-header-injection) :

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError

def send_email(request):
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
    message = request.POST.get('message', '')
    from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '')
    if subject and message and from_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')

    else:
        # In reality we'd use a form class
        # to get proper validation errors.
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

It's quick and dirty, but works fine.

However, it looks like you're still struggling with form handling inside django. You may want to work on that before moving on.

Good luck.